# This function gives me an error. I'm confused. I keep getting ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier

Tags: solidity, erc-20, error

```
 function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns (bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) => value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance)[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax error. I fixed them in this way:

Smart contract modified:

```
// your logic

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns (bool) { 
    require(balanceOf(from) >= value, "balance too low"); 
    require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, "allowance too low"); 
    balances[to] += value; balances[from] -= value; 
    emit Transfer(from, to, value); 
    return true; 
}

// your logic
```

Comment: Thank you so much I see my error. I appreciate it